# How to apply box shadow to individual images in Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap carousel with some images and I am trying to apply a box shadow to a few individual images but not all of them. This is the code I have right now...

```
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="width:960px;" data-interval="2000">
          <!-- Indicators -->
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3" class=""></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4" class=""></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="5" class=""></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="6" class=""></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="7" class=""></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="8" class=""></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="9" class=""></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="10" class=""></li>
          </ol>
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" id="myCarousel">
            <div class="item active" id="myCarousel">
              <img id="slidePic" style="width:960px;height:366px; box-shadow: 12px 0 15px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8), -12px 0 8px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8);" class="img-responsive" src="Pic/pic5.jpg" alt="First slide">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item" id="myCarousel">
              <img id="slidePic" style="width:958px;height:366px;" class="second-slide" src="Medrano Pics/Work Pict/collage10.png" alt="Second slide">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item" id="myCarousel">
              <img id="slidePic" style="width:958px;height:366px;" class="third-slide" src="Pic/WaterP/pic2.jpg" alt="Third slide">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item" id="myCarousel">
              <img id="slidePic" style="width:958px;height:366px;" class="third-slide" src="Medrano Pics/Work Pict/collage4.png" alt="Third slide">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item" id="myCarousel">
              <img id="slidePic" style="width:958px;height:366px; box-shadow: 12px 0 15px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8), -12px 0 8px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8);" class="third-slide" src="Pic/homePic1.jpg" alt="Third slide">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item" id="myCarousel">
              <img id="slidePic" style="width:958px;height:366px; box-shadow: 12px 0 15px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8), -12px 0 8px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8);" class="third-slide" src="Medrano Pics/Work Pict/collage11.png" alt="Third slide">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item" id="myCarousel">
              <img id="slidePic" style="width:958px;height:366px; box-shadow: 12px 0 15px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8), -12px 0 8px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8);" class="third-slide" src="Medrano Pics/Work Pict/collage8.png" alt="Third slide">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item" id="myCarousel">
              <img id="slidePic" style="width:958px;height:366px; box-shadow: 12px 0 15px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8), -12px 0 8px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8);" class="third-slide" src="Medrano Pics/Work Pict/collage18.png" alt="Third slide">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item" id="myCarousel">
              <img id="slidePic" style="width:958px;height:366px;" class="third-slide" src="Medrano Pics/Work Pict/collage21.png" alt="Third slide">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item" id="myCarousel">
              <img id="slidePic" style="width:958px;height:366px; box-shadow: 12px 0 15px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8), -12px 0 8px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8);" class="third-slide" src="Medrano Pics/Work Pict/collage22.png" alt="Third slide">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item" id="myCarousel">
              <img id="slidePic" style="width:958px;height:366px; box-shadow: 12px 0 15px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8), -12px 0 8px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8);" class="third-slide" src="Medrano Pics/Work Pict/collage23.png" alt="Third slide">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item" id="myCarousel">
              <img id="slidePic" style="width:958px;height:366px; box-shadow: 12px 0 15px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8), -12px 0 8px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8);" class="third-slide" src="Medrano Pics/Work Pict/collage24.png" alt="Third slide">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="left carousel-control" style="display: none;" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev" id="myCarousel">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" style="display: none;" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next" id="myCarousel">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
```

I've applied the box shadow to the image and I've tried applying the box shadow on the div with class="item" and class="item-active" but the box shadow doesn't show up. I've also tried placing the box shadow on the outermost div but that applies the box shadow to ALL the images which I dont want. Is there a way to apply a box shadow to a few images and not all of them?

Comment: what do you mean with few? (like the first n images, only odd or even index, ecc)

Comment: Every odd or even works for me. I can arrange the pictures as such but I was wondering if there was an easy way to apply the box shadows to "random" individual pictures

Comment: In odd/even I think there is a way with pure css, for random images I think it can be done only using js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the two methods I was talking about in my comments: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/silviagreen/3jsac33k/1/) [jsfiddle with box-shadow](https://jsfiddle.net/silviagreen/3jsac33k/2/)
You can modify the code to apply your css rule.

**even - odd**

```
.item:nth-child(even) img{ background: green;}
.item:nth-child(odd) img{background: red;}
```

**random**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var numItems = $('.item').length;

  function randomBoolean()
  {
    return Boolean( Math.round(Math.random()) );
  }

  $('.item').each(function(){

    if(randomBoolean() === true){
       $(this).css("background", "green");
    }else{
       $(this).css("background", "red");
    }


   });
  });
```

Comment: Dam you beat me to it. I am literally writing out a JS code for this but you've saved me a lot of time. Thank you

Comment: The css is very straight forward and clean. Using that solution, Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you extract the styling information from the HTML and transfer it to an external CSS file and create a class called "shadow" or similar. Then you can easily apply the box-shadow to any element by specifying a class name. This is better for testing what will work.

There are some additional issues with your code that could cause it to not render properly. For example, you can't have multiple elements with the same id. This will definitely cause errors.

```
<img id="slidePic" ... />
```

Comment: I agree with the ID part but how is creating a "shadow" class different from what I'm doing? I can't apply the style directly to the div or the img tags so I dont think creating a "shadow" class would help

Comment: I just meant to say it will help when you are placing the box shadows in different places, instead of copying the whole style attribute you can just use a class. It makes the code more readable as well. Did removing/changing the id attribute work?

Comment: Agreed thank you. It did not work when I changed the ID tags but very useful information none the less